# How do I make a local variable increase consistently in a recursive function having more than one calls?

Tags: java, recursion

In this code, I've used a global variable to increase the value of p whenever control touches the base case. But I want to do it without using a global variable. Is that possible?

```
public class stairCase {
static int p=0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int n = func(14,0);
    System.out.println(n);
}
public static int func(int n, int c){
    if(n==c){
        p++;
        return 1;
    }
    if(n-c>=1){
        func(n,c+1);
    }
    if(n-c>=2){
        func(n,c+2);
    }

    if(n-c>=3){
        func(n,c+3);
    }
    return p;
}}
```

Comment: `return func(n, c+x);`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're throwing away a major communication resource: the return value.  You recur in three places, but ignore the value.  Harness that, and you'll solve your problem.

Consider something like this:

```
if (n < c) return 0         // Jumping too far gives no solution
else if (n == c) return 1   // Jumping to the top step is 1 solution
else
    return func(n, c+1) +   // Other jumps: sum the solutions from
           func(n, c+2) +   //   each of the reachable steps.
           func(n, c+3)
```

For future programming, *please* learn about useful variable names and documentation.  I would not have followed this decently, had I not solved this problem yesterday in another posting.

---

You can do a little better with this problem if you reverse your counting.  Note that you never change **n** as you recur -- in that case, why pass it at all?  Start **c** at 14 and count to step 0 (the top).

Converting the code is left as an exercise for the student.  :-)